# how to add new object for each item in the list

Tags: c#, list, insert, addition

I have assigned data to a list like below.

```
   foreach (var items in niledetails)
            {
                cruiseDetails.Add(new CruiseDetails()
                {
                    mainID = items.cruiseID,
                    idL = items.idlength,
                    mainimageUrl = items.cruiseimageUrl,
                    adultPrice = items.adultprice,
                    location = items.cruiseLocation,
                    numberofDays = items.numberofdays,
                    description = items.description,
                    embarkationP = items.embarkationport,
                    cruiseTyp = items.cruisetype,
                    childPrice = items.childprice,
                    totalPrice = items.totalprice,
                    farecode = items.referenceNumber,
                    experience = items.cruiseName,
                    fullcategoryname = items.cruiseCabname
                });
            }
```

this works fine.this has 30 objects and for each object has 14 key/values.now what I want is to add additional value for each object in the list.

that means something like this

```
for(int i=0;i<cruiseDetails.Count();i++)
            {

                //for each object I want to add another key value( 15th) for all 30 objects.
            }
```

How can I do that. hope your help.

**NOTE : I'm not looking for this. EX:**

```
cruiseDetails.Insert(0, new someModel() { city = "All"});
```

Comment: so whats wrong with the for loop (or a foreach) option?

Comment: you don't want to modify existing model class to add new porpoerty?

Comment: what I want is to add the item number for each. as an example if the list has `30` objects, for each object I want to assign a property for `itemNumber`

Comment: I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<cruiseDetails.Count();i++)
{

    cruiseDetails[i].additionalKey = val;
}
```

try this code

Comment: nice it works fine.if you don't mind please tell me how it add to the list without using `Add` command.just to know.anyway thank your very much.I will accept this in few minutes. I upvoted. thank you.

Comment: My code didn't add to the list but it modified the already added elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (CruiseDetails myCruiseDetail in cruiseDetails){
  myCruiseDetail.myNewKey = myNewValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your properties in your loop

```
for(int i=0;i<cruiseDetails.Count();i++)
            {
               cruiseDetails[i].mynewproperty = somevalue;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something as this:

```
List<Tuple<int, CruiseDetails>> list = new List<Tuple<int, CruiseDetails>>();

CruiseDetails> sourceCruises = new List<CruiseDetails>();
int i = 0;
foreach (var c in sourceCruises)
{
    list.Add(new Tuple<int, CruiseDetails>(i, c));
    i++;
}
```